# What's wrong with this config transform?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have the following part of a web.base.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <!--   Reporting Services -->
      <endpoint name="ReportExecutionEndpoint" address="http://~MACHINENAMEREPLACEMENTTOKEN~/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="AuthenticatedBehavior" bindingConfiguration="ReportingServicesConfiguration" contract="ReportingWebService.ReportExecutionServiceSoap" />
      <!--   Custom Services    -->
      <endpoint name="Blah1Endpoint" address="net.tcp://~MACHINENAMEREPLACEMENTTOKEN~/DomainServices/blah1.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="AuthenticatedBehavior" bindingConfiguration="LargerMessagesConfiguration" contract="Fully.Qualified.IBlah1" />
      <endpoint name="Blah2Endpoint" address="net.tcp://~MACHINENAMEREPLACEMENTTOKEN~/DomainServices/blah2.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="AuthenticatedBehavior" bindingConfiguration="LargerMessagesConfiguration" contract="Fully.Qualified.IBlah2" />
      <endpoint name="Blah3Endpoint" address="net.tcp://~MACHINENAMEREPLACEMENTTOKEN~/DomainServices/blah3.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="AuthenticatedBehavior" bindingConfiguration="LargerMessagesConfiguration" contract="Fully.Qualified.IBlah3" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I want to add an `<identity><dns /></identity>` in for all of the *CustomServices* but not the *ReportingServices*. To do so, I have the following transform segment:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint xdt:Locator="Condition(contains(@address, 'net.tcp'))">
        <identity xdt:Transform="Insert">
          <dns value="~MACHINENAMEREPLACEMENTTOKEN~" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The problem is that this only does so for the **first** *CustomService* but not all of the others (although it correctly skips the *ReportingServices*). How can I change this transform so it hits all of my *CustomServices* endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that the Insert transform is designed is for single use. Because of this it will insert only the first match.

A workaround for you in this case would be to create an Insert transform for each net.tcp endpoint.

If you really need to get this done, you can create your own custom transform which can insert for multiple matches. I have blogged about how to do that at
http://sedodream.com/2010/09/09/ExtendingXMLWebconfigConfigTransformation.aspx.

Comment: Would I simply use Apply and add my new Identity node to TargetNode? Out of pocket at this moment but want to get this implemented tonight. Thanks!

Comment: In the constructor set ApplyTransformToAllTargetNodes to true then you can in the Apply method TargetNode.AppendChild(TransformNode); should do the trick. I didn't try that but that is my guess.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure I'll figure it out one way or another. Have a great night!

Comment: Thanks. If you are interested you could send a pull request to https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah.xdt to include the transform there as well. It's a different base class but you'll eventually have to switch to that class.